# Close ngbPopover on click outside anywhere other than scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, angular7, bootstrap-popover

I am using an ngpopover in my Angular 7 project to help user select date range.
I have created a daterange component implementing Onchanges and I am importing this wherever I need the ngbpopover.

***What I want to do.***

I want that when user clicks on scrollbar of window the popover should not autoclose but if user clicks anywhere outside the popover the popup should autoclose.

My code

**HTML FILE**

```
<div (scroll) = "onScroll($event)">
<ng-template #popContent>
------
</ng-template>


 <button type="button" class="btn btn-date-selector" [placement]="defaultPlacement" 
 [ngbPopover]="popContent" [autoClose]="false" data-container="body" #popOver="ngbPopover">
 </div>
```

I had tried to using scroll event to get to know when the user scrolls on a particular page
**TS FILE**

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) private onScroll($event:Event) {
console.log($event.srcElement.scrollLeft, $event.srcElement.scrollTop);
};
```

But the hostlistener is not working.

Since I am calling the Date-range component inside my main html page as a child component how can I even check for window scroll over the parent component?

Is there any way I can check if the user has clicked outside the popOver and just not on the window scrollbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have been able to do what i desired.
I created a method

```
(click)= onDateSelection($event) in my Datepicker HTML file
```

In my ts file i added functionality like this added a viewchild for ngbPopOver

```
@ViewChild('popOver') public popover: NgbPopover;

onDateSelection(event) {

 //after selection of date
 this.popover.close();
 
}
```

So that after Date is getting selected and emitted the Datepicker module should get closed on it's own.

Comment: This answer still does not attain the ultimate result and we can't really distinguish if the user has clicked on window scroll or not.